# EXCEL SORT VBA - Sort outside

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

This is working:

```
Columns("A:L").Sort Key1:=Range("L1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess, _
        OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
```

I need to:

```
Columns("A:L").Sort ***Key1:=Range("W1")***, Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess, _
        OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
```

Is normal to generate error! I don't want to `Columns("A:W").Sort`!

I need to sort *just* A:L by values on W1 using VBA.

Answer (score 2):

Well, logically it is improbable that sorting A:L by Column W makes sense, *without* including column W in the sorting. 
If you do so, you can repeat the same sorting process and A:L are shuffled again into a different order!
So, the only seemingly reasonable thing is to sort A:L,W:W, but Excel cannot do this (only one contiguous area, in the versions I know). Only solution: copy W:W next to L and sort A:M.

Comment: Hi, great that it helps. So, then please mark (accept) the answer so others can see that the issue has been solved (and I get some points, too :) ).